# test if collection contains 2 objects in any order with equals

Tags: spring-boot, junit

What is the best way to test in JUnit that a collection contains two complex objects?
I know that there is containsInAnyOrder(), but I have no control over the objects, as they are created via a REST API and stored in a database. I need them to be compared by equals, not by reference.

Alternatively, it would be sufficient if I can test whether some of their attributes equal, but since the method the test covers involves AsyncCircuitBreakers, I'm not sure of the order.

How can I make sure, the two objects are created in the database with the data I have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList(array), hasItems(yourItem1, yourItem2));
```

Don't forget to add equals and hashCode methods to implement in your item class. hasItem is a hamcrest method.